# Exception while writing raw-data to Avi (Using C++)

Tags: c++, video

As mentioned in a previous question I'm capturing two HD-Streams at the same time via a Blackmagic Decklink Card. For saving the streams I'm using VfW and if the file size exceeds 2GB I'm writing a new file. Now I became stuck in a certain line of my code. Here it is:

```
if(WaitForSingleObject( mutex, INFINITE ) == WAIT_OBJECT_0 ) 
    {
      if(Bufferl.size()>0&&Bufferr.size()>0)
      {
        framel =(char*)malloc(size*sizeof(char));
        framel = Bufferl.front();

        framer =(char*)malloc(size*sizeof(char));
        framer = Bufferr.front();

        //Delete first entry of Bufferl & Bufferr

        Bufferl.erase(Bufferl.begin());
        Bufferr.erase(Bufferr.begin());

        long size_frame=size;

        //Release Mutex

        ReleaseMutex(mutex); 

        //Write Streams

        hr = AVIStreamWrite(avi_left_s,frameCount_local,1,(BYTE*)framel,size_frame,0,NULL,NULL);

        if(hr!=0)
        {
            printf("\nError writing left Stream!\n");
            Sleep(3000);
        }

        hr = AVIStreamWrite(avi_right_s,frameCount_local,1,(BYTE*)framer,size_frame,0,NULL,NULL);

        if(hr!=0)
        {
            printf("\nError writing right Stream!\n");
            Sleep(3000);
        }

        byteswritten=byteswritten+size_frame;
```

This part is running parallel to the capturing. Bufferl and and Bufferr containing the data of the samples as a vector. If the buffer aren't empty I'm writing the existing frames (framel & framer, both char*) into the avi-files. The problem now occurs in this line:

```
hr = AVIStreamWrite(avi_right_s,frameCount_local,1,(BYTE*)framer,size_frame,0,NULL,NULL);
```

Sometimes the exception: Zugriffsverletzung beim Lesen an Position 0x249d0020. is thrown. If I set a breakpoint and running the code step by step it works. Please notice that the writing of the left frame works fine, just the right is not been written. So the problem must be the buffer of the right frame: Bufferr, but I don't get it. I'm treading the left and the right buffer in the exactly same way.

Hoping for some hints,

Comment: You memory management and/or sync is bad, it has nothing to do with video, avi, capture and APIs. How comes you `malloc` buffer and immediately overwriting the pointer.

Comment: What's the definitions of `Bufferr` and `framer`?

Comment: @ Roman: You're right I should definitly look at my memory accesses, @ Joachim: vector<char*> Bufferr; and char* framer; . Thx a lot!